# How to solve the boot Reference error in Quasar SPA application?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, runtime-error, quasar-framework

Using `quasar build` command, I made a quasar app web build, and dumped those files into the production domain folder. After, trying to access the domain, I am getting a blank page and error on console:

```
index.42944a7a.js:9  [Quasar] boot error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'nn' before initialization
    at app_core.d37db9c3.js:2:11982
```

after clicking on app_core error link, the code it pointing is:

```
var rn = ae.exports
  , Ge = rn;
const te = nn()
  , R = Ge.create({
    baseURL: te.urlD
});
```

Comment: Can you show the dist/spa folder output in your question and a screenshot of the page console where you got that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because I tried to access VueUse storage elements before the App initialization in axios boot file.